# Saving a Matrix on disc for later use in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, save

I want to save several big matrices (1024x1024) on the disk and use them later on, so that  I won't have to calculate them every time from the start.

How do I do it? and how do I read them for use later on?

Comment: The `docsearch` command in MATLAB is helpful for this kind of thing: `docsearch save` will find for you all the documentation about saving files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the `save` command.

```
save(filename,matrixname);
```

Comment: and both filename and matrixname are strings. E.g. save('myfile', 'a') if the matrix is called 'a'. Several matrices may be stored in the same file.